# how can i find localhost:22 line from Ismpect element

Tags: css

i'm using google chrome, when ever i'm inspecting elements some css rules define particular path like (template.css:44) but some properties are in locallhost:22 (body a {
color: #EB540A;), then how can i reach this property and where  this css is placed ??

Comment: They're probably inside the HTML document. Clicking on the rule should take you there

Comment: yes dear by doing this i have found css on right side and name of file is program, where it could resides ?

Comment: In the HTML document itself. The document that you are viewing. What does it say in line 22?

Comment: still i'm unable to find this file (programs) in my localhost folder

Comment: But what makes you think it's a program? It should be just the current HTML document that you are in. `localhost` is the web address, `22` the line number.

Comment: dear can i have ur email i may send u screen shots

Comment: You might be able to upload a screen shot in your question. Does that work?

Comment: no thats now works, thats why i asked for email.. !

Comment: ok, send me a screen shot. You can find my E-Mail in my profile

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your mouse and then click "view page source". Now one new window will open and you able to see the path of the css file(template.css) and you able to edit.

Comment: i have founded css setting within template.css but i wana find css setting within localhost:22